# ¿Cómo obtener la url de las categorias wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

En la plantilla de wordpress `archive.php` tengo un botón que quiero que me lleve a la categoría donde está.

Tengo este código :

```php
<?php
    // Get the ID of a given category
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'Category Name' );

    // Get the URL of this category
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );

    echo esc_url( $category_link ); 
?>
```

Cuando estoy aquí:

```
localhost/web/category/finanzas/
```

sí me da el *link* de la categoría, pero cuando hago la paginación cómo:

```
localhost/web/category/finanzas/page/2/
```

Me da el mismo link que tiene esa página, o sea, incluyendo el `page/2/`

¿Cómo hago, en wordpress o con alguna función, que me dé la categoría y no cambie cuando se pasa a otra página?

Comment: Hola. Si estás en la página 2 te devuelve localhost/web/category/finanzas/page/2/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que recortes la cadena de la url a partir de "/page" con un substr y un strpos, como sigue:

```
<?php
    // Get the ID of a given category
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'Category Name' );

    // Get the URL of this category
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );

    echo esc_url( substr($category_link, 0, strpos($category_link , '/page')); ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

basta con eliminar el segmento /page/###/ (si existe) con preg_replace:

`$fixed_link = preg_replace( '/page\/\d+\//', '', $link );`

La expresión regular va entre `/` diagonales, por lo que las diagonales de la URL las tienes que escapar con `\`, así : `\/` y la parte `\d+` quiere decir "uno o más dígitos"

Puedes hacer pruebas de esta solución aquí:
https://3v4l.org/V8dO7